# variable inside asset() in jquery inside laravel blade throws error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

This is string in jquery which is latter embedded inside laravel blade file . 
But this doesnot seems to be way to do it .

this is inside  tag

```
var addvar = 'uploads/'+data.data[key].indexer+'.'+data.data[key].thumb;

user_status += '<img style="height: 290px;" alt="360-video-feature" src=" 
{{asset(addvar)}}" alt="" />';
```

It throws error :

**Use of undefined constant addvar - assumed 'addvar'** .

Comment: Does `asset($addvar)` fix the problem?

Comment: nope this doesn't solve it

Comment: What output happens ?

Comment: @mulquin, this is jquery and u have give `$addvar`

Comment: I know, but `Use of undefined constant ...` is a PHP error

Comment: The way its currently setup this wont work - PHP is parsed before the JS (so its reading addvar as php) - for this to work `addvar` needs to be a php variable, so it becomes `$addvar` and even then it needs to be set before the page loads.

Comment: @Yeeooow : this would work `src="{{asset("/")}}'+addvar+'"`  first `{{asset("/")}}` will give path and then value of `addvar` will add to path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comment i went through different way to get that and did as

```
var base_url = '{!! url('/') !!}';
var name1 = '/uploads/'+data.data[key].video_id+'.'+data.data[key].thumb;
```

and wrote string as :

```
user_status += '<img style="height: 290px;" alt="360-video-feature"      
src="'+base_url+name1+'" alt="" />';
```

and Hurray it worked ... thanks all of u ...

Comment: i just did thanks ...  it worked thanks for ur answer

Comment: Although `url` and `asset` worked in this case for you but there is difference in other [for future ference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/asset-vs-url)

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` to add js variable

```
 user_status += '<img style="height: 290px;" alt="360-video-feature" src="'+addvar +'" alt="" />';
```

Using this `{{asset(addvar)}}`

Is like calling with constant `addvar` because neither it is a variable nor a function

To ensure about path use `/` before url in src

```
   var addvar = '/uploads/'....
```

If you want `asset()` use like this

```
user_status += '<img style="height: 290px;" alt="360-video-feature" src="{{asset("/")}}'+addvar+'" alt="" />';
```

Comment: it will not reference to right link if not written with asset() function

Comment: sorry but this wont work because asset has no argument and throw error as Type error: Too few arguments to function asset(),

Comment: put `/` as `asset("/")`

Comment: can u please help me on adding this on the string  like similar  Auth::find( data.data[key].user_id )->first_name

Comment: @pravinpoudel : can you please add another question for this ?

Comment: the code commented above will not work, it must be pass from `view` or use `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

I think `{!! url ('/') !!}` will be correct.